# Going to a page during WillEnterforeground in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a different iOS app that is built on Xamarin App. I have a requirements that when an app is idle and the user open his app again he will redirect to login page if his session is expired. Is there a way to redirect to a login page in Xamarin in the WillEnterForeground event AppDelegate?

```
public async override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        var msalService = new MsalAuthService();
        var isUserCurrentlyLogin = await  msalService.IsCurrentlyLogIn();

        if (!isUserCurrentlyLogin)
        {
            // Go To Login Page

        }
        else
        {
            // stay on the current page
        }

        base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
    }
```

Comment: is this a Forms app?  Forms has it's own `OnResume` event you can use to do this

Comment: Yes it is Forms app but OnResume doesn't work in iOS.

Comment: that's news to me - I've used it many times

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the OnResume but it didn't hit the breakpoint. I am testing on Simulator

Comment: when you send the app to the background the debugger usually becomes detached

Comment: Yes, but when you open the app again the debugger is automatically attached.  I set a breakpoint to WillEnterForeground and OnResume event. Only WillEnterForeground hit when I re-open the apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244811/discussion-between-ramdev-and-jason).

Comment: Perhaps debugger attaches too late for that breakpoint. Debug.WriteLine in OnResume to see if it gets there.